# Nginx return under location

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-redirect, nginx-location

I am currently facing a small problem using nginx to redirect to another host. I want to for example redirect https://service.company.com/new/test.html to https://new-service.company.com/test.html .

For now I have following configuration, which redirects me to https://new-service.company.com/new/test.html .

```
server {
        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/chained_star_company.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/star_company.com.key;

        listen 443;
        server_name service.company.com;

        location /new/$1 {
        return 301 $scheme://service-new.company.com/$1;
    }

}
```

I also tried following with the same result:

```
return 301 $scheme://service-new.company.com/$request_uri
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to rewrite the URI and redirect. You can achieve it using `location` and `return` directives, but a `rewrite` directive would be the simplest approach:

```
rewrite ^/new(.*)$ https://new-service.company.com$1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

BTW, the problem with your `location` block solution, was the regular expression capture, wasn't. Use:

```
location ~ ^/new(.*)$ {
    return 301 https://new-service.company.com$1$is_args$args;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.